# open ssh server back

Tags: ssh, shutdown

After I type `# shutdown -h now` from terminal, 
I can't access to the ssh remote server. (`ssh root@10.101.6.240)`

How should I open back the ssh server?

Comment: ... and then install `molly-guard` or the equivalent in your distribution.

Comment: once you powerdown your server, you must power it on ...

Answer (score 5):

You have to power on your device again as you are shutting your device down. 
And as commented by @ Atsby install **molly-guard** to prevent you from accidental shutdowns and reboots

Answer (score 4):

`shutdown -h now` powers off the device (flag `-h`=halt) immediately (`now`).

Quite obviously, once it is off you cannot connect to it anymore.  You need to manually power it again before you can do anything with it; in order to do this you need to have physical access to the server -- or, if it is a VM, access to the VM administration console.